# Bounds for central moments

Tags: probability-theory

Let X be a random variables. Suppose that we have $E(|X|^p) < \infty$ for all $p\ge 1$. Can we prove $E\left(|X - E(X)|^p\right) < \infty$ for all $p\ge 1$ ? Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for [some constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Proof) $C$ we have
$$
|X-EX|^p\leq (|X|+|EX|)^p\leq C(|X|^p+|EX|^p)\leq C\bigg(|X|^p+[E|X|]^p\bigg)
$$

---

[**Added**:] The value of $C$ is not important in this argument. (The point is that it is a positive real number.) But one can give one by noticing that
$$
|a+b|^p\leq[2\max(|a|,|b|)]^p\leq 2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p).
$$

Comment: You can set $C$ to $2^p$ because $|X-EX|^p \le (|X|+|EX|)^p\le (2\max\{|X|,|EX|\})^p \le 2^p(|X|^p+|EX|^p)$

Comment: I think that C should be $2^{p-1}$.

Comment: @Robin: the link I gave uses convexity of the function $x\mapsto x^p$. The positive number $2^p$ would work also.